# Mention field = null in child comments but works fine for root level comments

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

I want to make childComments nested in root comments. I did it. But the problem is that mention field = null in childComments but other fields are displayed correctly. However, for root comments, mention field works well.

I also want to have only two levels of comments.

Root comments -> child comments. And child comments shoul'd have childComments.
Perhaps I did not register the mapping correctly. I will be glad to hear your advice.

```
    @Override
      public CommentListResponse list(Specification<CommentEntity> spec, Pageable pageable, DeletedRecords deleted) {
        pageable = DefaultSorting.apply(pageable, Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("commentedAt")));
        spec = SpecificationHelper.addDeletedFilter(spec, deleted);
        Page<CommentEntity> page = commentRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
        List<CommentListResponse.CommentItem> comments = page.stream()
            .filter(comment -> comment.getParentCommentId() == null)
            .map(comment -> commentMapper.toListResponseItem(comment, deleted != null))
            .toList();
        return CommentListResponse.builder()
            .data(comments)
            .fromPage(page)
            .build();
      }
    
    
    @Data
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    public class CommentListResponse extends PagedResponse {
      private List<CommentItem> data;
    
      @Data
      @Builder
      @NoArgsConstructor
      @AllArgsConstructor
      public static class CommentItem {
        private long id;
        private String body;
        private List<String> mentions;
        private Long parentCommentId;
        private List<CommentItem> childComments;
    
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        private Boolean deleted;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        private boolean includeDeletedField;
    
        public Boolean getDeleted() {
          return includeDeletedField ? deleted : null;
        }
      }
    }
    
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface CommentMapper {
    
      @Mapping(source = "comment.mentionUsers", target = "mentions")
      CommentListResponse.CommentItem toListResponseItem(CommentEntity comment, boolean includeDeletedField);
    }
    
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "comment")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    public class CommentEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "id")
      @ToString.Include
      private Long id;
    
      @Column(name = "body", nullable = false)
      @ToString.Include
      private String body;
    
      @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinTable(name = "comment_user_mention",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
      private List<UserEntity> mentionUsers;
    
      @Column(name = "parent_comment_id")
      @ToString.Include
      private Long parentCommentId;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCommentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private List<CommentEntity> childComments;
}
   
JSON output: {       "id": 1,
                    "body": "test root comment",
                    "mentions": ["user-1"],
                    "parentCommentId": null,
                    "childComments": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "body": "test child comment",
                            "mentions": null, - // in db i have mention for this child comment but it's null. 
                            "parentCommentId": 1,
                               "childComments": [] // i don't want to see this field in child comments.
                        }
        ]
        }
```

Comment: Can you add Mapstruct's implementation of your mapper to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thats most probably because you didn't provide a method that maps `List<UserEntity>` to `List<String>`.
Just add such a default method and test if it works.